# How to set read timeout (read-timeout-millis 3.11V ) in latest datastax 4.x version in Cassandra

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

In *Cassandra 3.11v*, we set **read-timeout-millis** properties like below.

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      read-timeout-millis: 2000ms
```

But how can we set **read-timeout** properties in the latest *Cassandra DataStax 4.x(4.13)*?

As per the properties reference given by Cassandra DataStax, we don't find read-timeout https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/configuration/reference/

How can we set read-timeout properties in the latest Cassandra DataStax 4.x?

Comment: I even doubt that this property would do anything in Spring Data Cassandra. Should you set `spring.data.cassandra.request.duration` for this?

Comment: @M.Deinum You are suggesting to use `spring.data.cassandra.request.timeout` ?

Comment: Indeed as that is the one you should configure as the C* driver has no `read-timeout-millis` or anything related to that.